# I'm having trouble unwrapping my mug for Blender Guru's tutorial

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIUDZZMfGNI&list=PLqZq-Osz7wB4ggMSqhs22ONmkzIBgPA9R&index=18) tutorial here, and have gotten around to the 8:30 mark. Compared to how it's unwrapped in the tutorial, mine is completely off. How do I fix this, what's causing it to look so different?[image]

Comment: You seem to have missed a step in the tutorial.  Go back to the start of the tutorial and pay careful attention to the parts about marking seams.  You don't appear to have any seams on your cup, or at the minimum, they're not in the most useful places.

Comment: I got it, I needed to apply the scale. Thanks for the help